# USB to Serial adapter broken with Ubuntu 22.04 but

Tags: usb

I have a Silicon Labs CP2105 USB to Serial adapter chip on an embedded development board so I cannot change the chip.

When running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Kernel 6.5.0-14-generic) I get garbage in the serial stream through minicom.  I also lose the ability to send any serial data.

Connecting the same development board to Windows 11 tablet, all works fine so I know it's not an issue with the development board, embedded CP2105 or cabling.

On the Ububtu 22.04.1 machine, I can run an Ubuntu 18.0 VM and everything works fine so I know it's not the underlying hardware or minicom.

A Ubuntu 20.04 VM has the same issues as 22.04.

Does anyone know what might have changed between 18.04 and 20.04?
Has something changed in the way Ubuntu handles serial port?
Maybe a major driver change for the CP2105?
Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output of `stty < /dev/ttyUSBYourNumber`? Did the baud rate change?

Comment: Te baud rate mained the same, 115,200.  It appears as if my laptop can receive just fine.  It cannot send characters.  Sometimes unplugging the USB cable will clear the problem for a few moments.